# Node не может подключиться к бд mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

веб приложение на node не может подключиться к базе данных mongodb.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соответсвенно в catch попадает ошибка которая отображается в консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал всё перезагружать, очищать, ничего не помогало. Надеюсь поможите вы, спасибо